# Copy text to clipboard with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, copy, clipboard

What is the best way to copy text to the iPhone's clipboard in your application?

Their docs are sketchy and have way more features than what I want... I just want to set a string as the users clipboard.

Comment: it's been 7 years and you still haven't accepted the correct answer below

Comment: Can't a mod accept the answer on his behalf?

Comment: Please accept an answer for this question.

Answer (score 635):

Although the accepted answer is a good walkthrough of how `UIPasteboard` works, I figured I'd post the relevant snippet right here for everyone's convenience:

Obj-C

```c
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = @"Paste me!";
```

Swift 2.2

```swift
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteBoard.string = "Paste me!"
```

Swift 3+:

```swift
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.general
pasteBoard.string = "Paste me!"
```

Comment: Thanks for that, much more helpful than sifting through a big tutorial.

Comment: Yep, thanks for this. This is IMO how a question should be answered.

Comment: Even in 2017 this is still the accepted answer to be.

Answer (score 35):

Swift 2.2 :

```
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pasteBoard.string = "Paste Me !"
```

Swift 3:

```
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.general
pasteBoard.string = "Paste me!"
```