# How do you copy a string onto the clipboard (Pasteboard) in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, copy-paste, uipasteboard

How do you copy a string onto the clipboard in iOS?  I searched for "clipboard" in the docs, and got no hits.

Comment: "UIPasteboard" will give better results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy text to clipboard with iPhone SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479468/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
    [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].string = @"hello!";
```

Apple doesn't use the term "clipboard";  in iOS it's a "pasteboard", and you can have more than one of them.

Answer (score 0):

In `Swift 3.0` below code will help to copy text on `PasteBoard`

```
let pasteBoard = UIPasteboard.general
pasteBoard.string = "Lorem Ipsum"
```