# iOS - Copying a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

In my app users can send messages to each other. I use UITextView inside of a bubble image to display the chat history.

```
        [messageTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(padding, padding+5, size.width,     size.height+padding)];
        [messageTextView sizeToFit];
        messageTextView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteBubble"];
        UIImageView *bubbleImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:24 topCapHeight:15]];

        messageTextView.editable=NO;

        [bubbleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(padding/2, padding+5,
                                         messageTextView.frame.size.width+padding/2, messageTextView.frame.size.height+5)];


        [cell.contentView addSubview:bubbleImage];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:messageTextView];
```

Currently, when a user holds down on the message text, they see the 'Copy' and 'Define' options with cursors to select text.

However, I would rather have the basic iOS messaging option of holding down on a chat bubble to copy the entire message. How can this be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884243/how-to-copy-string-to-clipboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would subclass UITextView to implement your own version of the copy menu. You can do it a number of ways, but one possible way is like below.

The basic idea is that the text view sets up a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` that will create the popup menu when a long press is detected.

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` has several default system menus that will show up unless you tell them not to. The way to do that is to return `NO` for any selectors that you don't want to handle in `canPerformAction:withSender:`. In this case, we're returning `NO` for any selector except for our custom `copyText:` selector.

Then that selector just gets a reference to the general `UIPasteboard` and sets it's text to the text of the TextView.

In your subclass's implementation:

```
@implementation CopyTextView

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setup {
    self.editable = NO;
    self.selectable = NO;

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressDetected:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.3f; // however long, in seconds, you want the user to have to press before the menu shows up
    [self addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
}

- (void)longPressDetected:(id)sender {
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    if (longPress.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        UIMenuItem *menuItem = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Copy" action:@selector(copyText:)];

        UIMenuController *menuCont = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];

        [menuCont setTargetRect:self.frame inView:self.superview];

        menuCont.arrowDirection = UIMenuControllerArrowDown;
        menuCont.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:menuItem];
        [menuCont setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
}


- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return YES; }

- (void)copyText:(id)sender {
    UIPasteboard * pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pasteboard setString:self.text];
}

- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {
    if (action == @selector(copyText:)) return YES;
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Useful documentation:

[UILongPressGestureRecognizer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILongPressGestureRecognizer_Class/)

[UIMenuController Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/index.html)

Comment: perfect answer for me, thank you! where should I send the free beer :)