# Sharing vs. Copying

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, hashtag

I developed a codenameone app which copies some text (hashtags) to the clipboard and pastes it in another app. (for example facebook, twitter, instagram, linkedin etc etc) Copying is functioning well within the android build but within the ios build this is not the case. I was told that clipboard copying is not implemented in ios. I should rather use the "share API". Well for facebook there is an implementation for facebookshare but for other socialmedia platforms not. This means I have to write about 15 or more share services :(

and why on earth is ios clpboard copying not implemented?

Is there a generic way to do this, I mean some way valid for all platforms?

babur

Answer (score -1):

Sharing is implemented natively on iOS/Android and works with everything that's already installed on the device e.g. if you have whatsapp it will work with that etc...

It's the standard way of sharing between applications and that's what most people use. Copy & paste isn't as common once share is implemented so no one complained about the issue until now. If there is no issue in the issue tracker things like that don't get noticed. Even if there is an issue we generally schedule things people care and complain about.

Comment: What if I cannot use the device's copy function because of the data representation on the app's screen?
On the other hand, in android you have realized copy to clipboard and paste from it. And in the documentation there is not a word about that it is not realized in ios.

Have I known at the beginning that codenameone is not able to realize the most basic copy function in ios, I would have chosen another platform to develop my apps

Comment: Share works for 99% of the users and is "the right thing" so no one ever complained about copy() not being implemented. If bugs or missing features aren't reported in any project they don't get fixed or implemented. This is trivial to do using native interfaces with just two lines of code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479468/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-iphone-sdk