# what does execute in program?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
UIPasteboard *clipboard = UIPasteboard.General;
clipboard.string =  @"string being added to clipboard";
```

that is error Property 'General' not found on object of type 'UIPasteboard'
and this code will actually where execute?

Comment: ⌘-click on `UIPasteboard` and read the header file or use code completion.

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct format.You need to change to below format

```
UIPasteboard *clipboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
clipboard.string = @"string being added to clipboard";
```

[Copy text to Clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479468/copy-text-to-clipboard-with-iphone-sdk)